# Connecting input to numbers

Tags: java

So the user should be able to write the number of things bought and then get a message showing how many points they have depending on how much they bought. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int variable;

    System.out.println("Please write the number of CD:s you bought:");
    variable = scanner.nextInt();

    //So it should be: 1 = 5, 2 = 15, 3 = 30 and 4 = 60. But i cant seem to figure it out 

    if (variable < 0) {
      System.out.println("You have 0 points");
    }
    if (variable < 1) {
      System.out.println("You have 5 points");
    }
    if (variable < 2) {
      System.out.println("You have 15 points");
    }
    if (variable > 3) {
      System.out.println("You have 30 points");
    }
    if (variable > 4) {
      System.out.println("You have 60 points");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "Not working" isnt a working problem description. Hint: include expected **and** actual output. Also note: consider learning about using if + else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it like that?

```
if(variable == 0){
    System.out.println("0 Points");
} else if(variable == 1){
    System.out.println("5 Points");
} else if(variable == 2){
    System.out.println("15 Points");
} else if(variable == 3){
    System.out.println("30 Points");
} else if(variable == 4){
    System.out.println("60 Points");
} else if(variable > 4){
    System.out.println("More than 60 Points");
}
```

Comment: @HugoNilsson if ur answer is this answer u should approve it to give ur thx to funky !

Comment: If this helped, please accept the question in a day.